# Print SQLite query in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, bindvalue

I'm using PHP with SQLite3 to manage some website sessions and I'm having troubles with a query that doesn't return results. The thing is I want to print the query before the `execute` command but I can't find the way to do it.

More specifically, I'm using bindValue to generate the query and I need to print the generated statement after that or the query executed by sqlite. My code is something like this:

```
if (($db = new SQLite3('/var2/db/core.db', SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY)) == null)
{
    return false;
}
$user = 'user1';
$db_user_query = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username';

$stmt = $db->prepare($db_user_query);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $db->escapeString($user), SQLITE3_TEXT);
// Print the generated query
$result = $stmt->execute();
// Or print the queried statement.
```

**Edit:**
I want to print to a log something like:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username="user1"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're using prepared statements/placeholders. You do **NOT** manually escape your query values when using those. That will effectively DOUBLE escape the value, and if the value contains any sql metacharacters, probably cause a "no rows" result.

Comment: Now you have to process the result set that will have been built **but not automatically processed**  by your query Using one of the `sqlite_fetch_*` functions/methods

Comment: Thanks @Marc B for the advice, I deleted the `escapeString()` function. In this case the problem remains.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I wasn't clear (I will edit the question). I want to print the query (the string "SELECT ....") that will be executed to a log before fetching the results.

Comment: maybe you should post the query which gives you Problems. You could print the query if you use PDO as wrapper which has the method debugDumpParams(void). 
But you should know anyway what you Input in the params...
But even with PDO you have to execute before you can retrive the dump.
The whole sense behind the prepared stament is that the full query only exists after execute it

Comment: you can't get the raw "generateD" statement, unless prepared statement emulation is enabled. The query string you prepared and the values are normally not combined anywhere inside PHP - that's all done within the DB engine, and only immediately before data hits the disk. prepared statements aren't just a fancy wrapper around a bunch of `escape` calls and string concatenation.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the explanation. Considering that, is there a way to get it after the `execute`? Something like the db telling what query was executed.

Comment: you can get metadata about the query, usually. rows matched, sql status codes, blah blah blah, and the statement object will contain the query string you provided to the prepare call, but it won't have the values you bound - not in the sql string. bound values and the query string are kept strictly separated. combining them would simply open up the system to sql injection attacks again.

Comment: @MarcB Considering the things you're saying, I think I will change my strategy to look over the execution getting the sql status codes instead of trying to generate the query. Thanks for your help!